# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_sqlite3.dll

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite3

Доброго всем дня. Поставил новенький xubuntu 16.04, web сервер и yii2. 
В db.php прописал

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'sqlite:'.__DIR__ . '/phone.db',
```

Собственно постоянно вылетает ошибка

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_sqlite3.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_sqlite3.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Причем если раз пять нажать f5 ошибка пропадает и все работает как положено. Данные из бд читаются записываются.

Подскажите чего делать?

Comment: В антивирусе исключение поставить на файл бд :)

Comment: В антивирусе? под убунтой?

Comment: dll на linux'е!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы попытались в настройках PHP подключить библиотеку SQLite3, скомпилированную под Windows. Библиотеки для PHP имеют расширение `.so` и как правило устанавливаются через менеджер пакетов.

Найдите и удалите строку `extension=php_sqlite3.dll` (в `php.ini` или в одном из файлов в `/etc/php5/mods-available/`) и перезапустите PHP-FPM.

Comment: Вот тут аналогичный случай, только была подключена другая библиотека: http://askubuntu.com/questions/776322/startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-usr-lib-php-20151012-php-mbstring-dll

Comment: Всего то. А я панику поднял. Спасибо!